# Android getExtra always returning null

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am creating an intent and adding an extra parameter to it:

```
public void stop(View v) {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int currentVolume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(CANCEL_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra("volume", currentVolume);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I get the intent in my BroadcastReceiver, but the "volume" is always null:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.hamm.ringeroff.cancel")) {
            String _volume = intent.getStringExtra("volume");
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?  It has to be something simple.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `currentVolume` variable is never null?

Comment: given just the code that you posted here `currentVolume` is not instantiated and thus is `null` so this would be the expected behavior... In fact `currentVolume` isn't even declared in this code, so this shouldn't even compile. Please post the section of your code where you declare and instantiate `currentVolume`. A debugging step that you can take is to print it to the log before you add it to the intent, that will tell you for sure what its value is when you add it.

Comment: What is data type of currentVolume, int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either currentVolume is String and null or it is int in which case, use getIntExtra